# False EventID 7022 error

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

There's a old server with Windows 2003 SP2. We installed a custom service written in C# (.NET 4). Everyday there's a mandatory reboot and every day there's EventID 7022 error saying that our custom service hung on start. But, 20 seconds later eventlog shows EventID 7036 message saying that our custom service has successfully started.

How do we fix this? I suppose there's some kind of timeout set for service to become started, but how do we extend this timeout?

Please help.